# Oracle SQL commands that work when executed separately does not work when executed together. Why?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is regarding a migration script. The required migration can be done by using 4 separate SQL commands. However, when they are combined to run as a script I am getting **PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol** error.

These are the SQL commands that I've used to do the migration. The table will have a PK which is a composite key of 3 columns in the table. First I need to remove the constraint, then add a new column called ID to that table, make it auto incremental by adding a sequence and then make it the new PK of the table.

Following commands work and does the exact job when I execute them one by one.

```
BEGIN
  FOR item IN (
    SELECT *
       FROM all_constraints
       WHERE table_name = 'TEST_DB_CHANGE'
  )
  LOOP
   EXECUTE immediate 'ALTER TABLE TEST_DB_CHANGE DROP CONSTRAINT ' || item.CONSTRAINT_NAME;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_DB_CHANGE_SEQUENCE START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 nomaxvalue';
END;
/
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TEST_DB_CHANGE ADD (ID NUMBER DEFAULT TEST_DB_CHANGE_SEQUENCE.nextval)';
END;
/
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TEST_DB_CHANGE ADD CONSTRAINT TEST_DB_CHANGE_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)';
END;
```

But when they are executed together I get the following error.
*Query execution failed

```
Reason:
SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 11, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" *
```

I tried removing the "/" from that line, from every line, from every line except the last line, but none of that fixed the issue. Then the error will change to:

```
Reason:
SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 12, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: remove that "/" on your script

Comment: Remove all the `/` from your script and put only one `/` at the end of the whole script.
`/` Represents the end of the script.

Comment: Removing `/` does not help. Then it will give the same error but with the 'BEGIN' keyword. _PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" _

Comment: why do you have each Statement in a separate block?

Comment: Where are you running this? In SQL*Plus? Toad? PL/SQL Developer? SQL Developer? Something else? Also, why are you using PL/SQL to do your DDL instead of just running the DDL statements?

Comment: i have tried to execute it in SQL Window of plsql developer and it works without any issues. you are probaly use the wrong window type to execute your script.

Comment: Why do you have one PL/SQL block for each EXECUTE? Why don't you put everything into a single PL/SQL block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you have combined them but it should be:

```
BEGIN
  FOR item IN (
    SELECT *
       FROM all_constraints
       WHERE table_name = 'TEST_DB_CHANGE'
  )
  LOOP
   EXECUTE immediate 'ALTER TABLE TEST_DB_CHANGE DROP CONSTRAINT ' || item.CONSTRAINT_NAME;
  END LOOP;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_DB_CHANGE_SEQUENCE START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 nomaxvalue';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TEST_DB_CHANGE ADD (ID NUMBER DEFAULT TEST_DB_CHANGE_SEQUENCE.nextval)';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TEST_DB_CHANGE ADD CONSTRAINT TEST_DB_CHANGE_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)';
END;
```